# Intercepting the jsp compiled PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate

Tags: jsp

We have usages of many EL's inside out JSP's. These JSP's are in turn converted into Java files and the EL's in it are resolved using the PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate.

Is there any way i can intercept the static proprietaryEvaluate so that i can override it's implementation. Dynamic Proxies can't be used since only the methods defined inside the Interface gets intercepted.

This might sound hacking around but we have certain use cases where inside our Spring app we directly hit a view, without loading it's model; in which case we would populate some test data via the proprietaryEvaluate.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue or find a workaround?

Comment: No we weren't. But what we did was to setup mock models via dependency injection (spring configuration file) for the pages.